При установке Kubuntu с автоматической разметкой разделов на свободное место рядом с Windows 10, установленной ранее, возникает ошибка
Подскажите пожалуйста, что делать. Я сначала установил Windows 10 на ноутбук, а затем сделал загрузочную флешку с образом Kubuntu 24.10. Я начал автоматическую установку в режиме "Заменить раздел" и в конце её выдало ошибку "Загрузчик установить не удалось. Команда установки grub-install --target=x86_64-efi --efi-directory=/boot/efi --bootloader-id=ubuntu --force вернула код ошибки 1."
Разделы до установки Kubuntu выглядели примерно так:
-dev/sda1 529 МиБ NTFS
-dev/sda2 (Windows Boot Manager) 100 МиБ FAT32
-dev/sda3 16 МиБ (Kubuntu выдаёт "неизвестный")
-dev/sda4 226.81 ГиБ NTFS
-Свободное место 238.32 ГиБ
Kubuntu пишет, что её дело состоит в:

Удалить dev/sda5 (ранее этого этапа не было, потому что раздела не было. Я уже несколько раз пытался установить Kubuntu, поэтому сейчас там уже раздел, но при заходе в этот раздел через bios выдаёт текст и командную строку с >grub (примерно так))
Создать новый раздел 244039 МиБ (цитирую, но на русском) раздел в /dev/sda с kubuntu 2410
"Set up fat32 partition /dev/sda2 with mount point /boot/efi..." думаю, что здесь переведу некорректно
Установить Kubuntu в новый ext4 системный раздел.

Я заметил, что при установке он пытается взять откуда-то ещё 6 ГиБ, ибо создаёт раздел 244 ГиБ, а не 238. Также понятия не имею, что он делает с разделом, установленным ещё Windows 10 до начала его установки.
Добавлю, что до этого пытался установить на него Arch Linux, в итоге не смог изменить основной раздел Windows, поставил Windows 10 заново, предварительно оставив место для Arch, из за неопытности бросил установку Arch, слишком сложно для меня. В итоге разделы Windows больше не трогал, а разделы Arch удалил, чтобы осталось свободное место. Возможно Arch внёс какие-то изменения, не знаю. Я проводил ручную установку, ну то есть вручную монтировал разделы, дошёл до установки загрузчика Grub, уж не помню, получилось ли у меня его установить, видимо не получилось, ибо я бросил это дело. Ноут Lenovo Ideapad 320 15IAP.
Помогите пожалуйста разобраться

Всё установилось, сменил в Boot Menu UEFI на Legacy Support

Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы в Справке.
